# Can't deserialize DateTime in NativeQuery with Java / Hibernate

Tags: java, json, jackson, jodatime

*Simplified examples*

I run a native query with date in it:

```
SELECT id, start FROM event;
```

I did a SqlResultSetMapping like:

```
@SqlResultSetMapping(
        name="EventMapping",
        classes={
                @ConstructorResult(
                        targetClass=de.teamsystems.domain.OverviewEvent.class,
                        columns={
                                @ColumnResult(name="id", type = Long.class ),    
                                @ColumnResult(name="start", type = DateTime.class )

                        }
                )
        }
)
```

And my OverviewEvent class looks like:

```
@Entity
public class OverviewEvent  {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    private String name;


    private DateTime start;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public DateTime getStart() {
        return start;
    }

    public OverviewEvent(Long id, DateTime start) {
        this.id = id;
        this.start = start;
    }
```

}

When I execute this code in my controller, I get the following exception:

```
{
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "exception": "javax.persistence.PersistenceException",
    "message": "org.hibernate.type.SerializationException: could not deserialize",
    "path": "/event",
    "status": 500,
    "timestamp": "2017-03-13T22:22:30.527+0100"
}
```

The log files say:

```
2017-03-13 22:22:30.523 ERROR 23479 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.type.SerializationException: could not deserialize] with root cause

java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 32303137
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:808) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
```

When I change the DateTime into String in the OverviewEvent class and in the SqlResultSetMapping, it works. But I would like to work with the datetime format.

Does anyone can help me with that exception. I tried different things such as:

```
@Type(type = "org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateTime")
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
private DateTime start;
```

But the exception stayed the same. Thanks for helping me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `Date` `(java.util.Date)` instead of `DateTime`:

```
  @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
  private Date start;
```

or create a custom de/serializer for DateTime.

Comment: Thanks. I will try that once I am on the project again this evening. As I am a newbie is it this what you are talking about:

http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-custom-serialization

http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-deserialization

Comment: Worked. Thanks a lot